# how to increase the speed of the calculation of adfuller coefficients in python?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a dataframe where each column is price spreads of two stocks per days.
To calculate adfuller coefficients, i used the next script:

```
adf_spreads = {}
for col in df_spread.columns.values[1:]:  
    adf_spreads[col] = adfuller(df_spread[col])
```

It works well, but if the number of columns increases, it significantly increases the amount of time required for adfuller coefficients calculation.

Are there any ways how to speed up this process? Maybe is there another way how to replace for-loop?

Comment: how many columns do you have? what's the `shape` of your table? normally iterating through columns is not so bad in pandas. You could replace your `for` with an `apply` or `map` over columns, but I don't expect you'd get much speedup

Comment: @mitoRibo i have near 2000 columns (the number of stocks that i research to find two cointegrated stocks for pair trading)